# My Ubuntu 16.04 is running very slow

Tags: 16.04, performance

I am using Ubuntu 16.04-i386 and I've been facing this issue from last few hours, I was trying to install Valgrind (Memory check tool) in my Ubuntu, so I installed the package from the website. I wanted to copy that package in `usr/local/src`, but at that time I was not having any permissions to that folder, I gave myself permissions just for `/usr` folder by doing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and `gksu nautilus` and after doing that I installed my package.
I updated my Ubuntu by using Software Updater, it was just 2.83 MB of update.
and I am doing some C programming by using `malloc()`.

I am telling you all this because I am not aware of the reason why my Ubuntu is running slow after doing all those things I've just mentioned above and I am pretty sure like its not related to C language or `malloc()`.

My PC is running Very very very SLOW,I tried to restart my PC, and it was stuck on Ubuntu screen for several minutes, after rebooting the PC and entering my password I found no change. 
So, I decided to change permissions again and now I am not able to open `gksu nautilus`. Please help me out.

And sorry for the formatting as I am new here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anyone who's gonna help me out ?

Comment: What is your specs? Kinda need more info man

Comment: Does it run slow with a lot of disk IO, or with a lot of CPU (even if the system is too slow to reach a CPU meter, the noise of the CPU fan is usually a good indicator of CPU overload)?

Comment: Nope,Idk what does that mean but my whole PC is running slow, eclipse is opening very slowly,Firefox has the same problem.. and no CPU sound @xenoid

Comment: my specs is like my Ubuntu sucks (sorry,I love Ubuntu) but Idk the reason. My nautilus is not working. I am clicking on the icon and nothing is happening.@Inforcer25

Answer (score 0):

Check running processes and RAM usage by running `top` command in a terminal. Check it using a text mode console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) if you believe the slowness is related to Xorg/GUI.

And BTW, you could have installed valgrind from the ubuntu repositories (`sudo apt-get install valgrind`, or using the software center), instead of compiling it by yourself, would be a lot less work.

I´m not sure what permissions you changed on `/usr`, but if you changed the ownership of the whole `/usr` recursively you are in trouble... Probably easier/faster to reinstall Ubuntu than to fix it.

Comment: Ctrl+alt+F1 , well I just tried this and guess what its not opening(stuck on the dark purple color,not good with colors name, but its the common Ubuntu color which we see while rebooting the PC where it shows Ubuntu). and yeah I could've done that but IDK why I did that but now its done . and yeah /usr part, I clicked properties->permissions->change permission for enclosed files and inside that I changed everything into read and write , change and delete.

Comment: I don't want to reinstall it please if there is any other way to fix this issue. Or if there is some way to get into nautilus, because its not opening for me.